# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript

Me sale este error pero no se por que, intento hacer el efecto de thanos a una imagen

Este es mi script

```
<script> 

    $("#start-btn").click(function(){

  html2canvas($(".content")[0]).then (canvas => {
    //capture all div data as image
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var pixelArr = imageData.data;
    createBlankImageData(imageData);
    //put pixel info to imageDataArray (Weighted Distributed)
    for (let i = 0; i < pixelArr.length; i+=4) {
      //find the highest probability canvas the pixel should be in
      let p = Math.floor((i/pixelArr.length) *canvasCount);
      let a = imageDataArray[weightedRandomDistrib(p)];
      a[i] = pixelArr[i];
      a[i+1] = pixelArr[i+1];
      a[i+2] = pixelArr[i+2];
      a[i+3] = pixelArr[i+3]; 
    }
    </script>
```

El navegador chrome me marca el error en esta linea que es de las primeras

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que estas incluyendo mal el método, como dice el error estás *[tainted](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Imagen_con_CORS_habilitado)*(Contaminando) la información inicial, puedes prevenirlo usando:

```
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

Para que funcione desde un servidor remoto has de poner en el mismo:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```